# XCode: How to resize views, buttons depending on the screen size of the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

My app contains several view controllers. I have used auto layout to add constraints to my labels, views and buttons. 
This is how one of the screens looks like on iPhone X.

[image: How it looks like on iPhone X]

How the sam screen looks like on iPhone 8

[image: How it looks like on iPhone 8]

As you can see, the disclaimer text in the iPhone 8 image is not fully showing.
How would I get it to show on iPhone 8, iPhone SE, etc?
Thank you

Comment: Most probably the reason is either wrong constraint given between Disclaimer and Sydney label or view or you forgot to give vertical constraint between those view or lable, so please check those constraint. as well check your Xcode logs, it will help you to find the actual reason like which constraint is creating problem.

Comment: I have correctly added the constraints. But could it be happening because my screen size is too small and thus its not fitting in there?

Comment: No your screensize will not create any problem.

Comment: @DhavalD.  Then what must be causing the problem? The constraints are blue coloured indicating that there are no problems?

Comment: You set static constraints in iPhoneX while the screen has larger height rather than iPhone8, maybe the best solution is set constraints in iphone5 or smaller screens, also you could use 'Autoresizing' option

Comment: @arash autoresizing sounds like a good idea, however is it possible to add constraints with auto resizing?

Comment: yes it is possible, you can set constraints (for example: just for top and left) and let autoresizing do the rest, but I think its not a good idea to use constraint for pages which has full of elements

Comment: @arash I see. Since my page is full of elements, I would be better off setting constraints in iphone5 or smaller screens right?

Comment: yeah that's it, when you design your vc in small screens you are sure that design remains perfect in larger screens while you use autoresizing